# rails, carrierwave, multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I am working on my first rails application and I am attempting to setup multiple image uploads in a form. I have created a contest which has many contest entries, and contest entries can have many images. I have the contest entry piece working, but I am having trouble getting the image upload portion of the form working. I am following this tutorial http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/ linked to from the carrier wave wiki.

contest entry model

```
class ContestEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :contest_id, :entry_images_attributes
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :contest_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :contest
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :entry_images, as: :imageable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entry_images
end
```

Entry image model

```
class EntryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alt, :image_path

  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :image_path, presence: true

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

New entry form

```
<%= nested_form_for([:contest, @entry], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :contest_id %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>

    <%= f.fields_for :entry_images do |builder|  %>
        <p>
        <%= builder.label :alt %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :alt %>
        </p>
        <p>
        <%= builder.label :image_path %><br />
        <%= builder.file_field :image_path %>
        </p>

    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Image", :entry_images %></p>

    <%= f.submit "Enter", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults,"nested_form" %>
```

for some reason nothing shows up in the <%= f.fields_for :entry_images do |builder|  %> block. It is just blank there is also no error message. if I switch it to 
<%= f.fields_for :entry_image do |builder|  %> and switch to using a form_for instead of the nested_form_for plugin all the fields show up but I get errors when I submit.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Cory

Comment: I cannot be sure what goes wrong , but in case you're using a recent version of `nested_form` gem , you should remove `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults,"nested_form" %>` on the last line of the view.

Comment: Hi Qumara, It was all a asset pipeline problem.

Comment: Nice to hear you've found the solution . What was the thing exactly ?

Comment: I am building a rails based contest. User can submit images in contests and other users vote for winners.

Comment: Is it alive already ? I'd love to see it.